# JS uncaught error when Promise finally is used in function

Tags: javascript, promise

Here is JS code:

```
function createPromise() {
  const result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      reject(new Error('my error'));
    }, 2000);
  });
// uncomment this to get error
//  result.finally(() => {
//     console.log('finally before');
//  });

  return result;
}

function test() {
  createPromise()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('promise then');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('promise catch:', error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      console.log('promise finally');
    });
}
```

Its works properly and after  executing I have in the console:

> promise catch: Error: my error
> promise finall

But after uncommenting:

```
result.finally(() => {
     console.log('finally before');
  });
```

In console I have uncaught exception:

> finally before
> promise catch: Error: my error
> promise finally
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: my error

Why is this happening and how to explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The unhandled promise**

Like `.then` and `.catch`, `.finally` returns a promise. But unlike `.catch` or `.then` with a second argument supplying an `onrejection` handler, `finally` does not fulfill the promise it returns if the previous promise in the chain becomes rejected.

So the expected output without the comments for the `result` promise is the same. But in addition there is the promise returned by `.finally` **in `createPromise`** that doesn't have a rejection handler. Hence the uncaught promise rejection error.

The `.finally` in function `test` is okay because the preceding catch clause fulfills the promise it returned so `.finally` won't reject the promise it returned.

---

**More about the `finally` method of a promise**

- Generally a `.finally` clause passes through the result, or promise rejection reason, of the previous promise in a promise chain to the next promise in the chain.
- However, if `finally` handler code throws an error or returns a rejected promise when called, the next promise in the chain is rejected for the same error or rejection reason - any data or rejection reason arriving from previous promises in the chain is effectively discarded.

---

**How to stop `finally` handler code generating uncaught rejection errors.**

1. Return the chain formed by calling `finally` on the new Promise:

   ```
    function createPromise() {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            reject(new Error('my error'));
          }, 2000);
        })
        .finally( () => {
          console.log('finally before');
        });
    }
   ```

   If the `finally` handler throws or returns a rejected promise, such thrown value or rejection reason rejects the promise synchronously returned when `finally` was called, leaving it to the caller of `createPromise` to handle.
2. A second method to suppress uncaught rejection reasons is to add a dummy `catch` handler, although this is rarely used and not recommended in most cases.

   ```
    result.finally(() => {
      console.log('finally before');
    })
    .catch( err => err); // avoid unhandled rejection
   ```

   would handle promise rejection originating from within the `finally` handler (or promise rejection of `result`) by having `catch` return a fulfilled promise that is never used.

Comment: "*But unlike the first two, `.finally` does not fulfill the promise*" - `then` and `catch` don't do that either.

Comment: @Bergi updated to exclude `then` calls with only one argument, thanks for pointing it out. However it may be worth noting that `catch` does fulfill its returned promise if the rejection handler doesn't throw or return a rejected promise.

Comment: Yes, "*iff the rejection handler doesn't throw*". In short, `then` resolves the returned promise with the result of the respective handler, or if no handler was supplied, forwards the resolution. (Same for `catch`, which never has a fulfillment handler). And `finally` works the same way: it doesn't have any *handler* for fulfillment or rejection, it always forwards the resolution, just like `.then(null, null)` or `.catch(null)`.

Comment: @Bergi ??? `finally` doesn't "alway" forward the previous promise's resolution - I hope to have covered the exceptions under the 2nd bullet point.

Comment: Oops, right, exceptions/rejections from the `finally` callback still take precedence.

Comment: Actually the cause why is it happening was a little bit hard to understand (maybe only for me), so I'll leave a comment here for those, who can't understand why this happens. So we create a promise, and assign it to `result` variable. After that `finally` creates his own promise which will be resolved or rejected based on the promise it is handling. So now we have *2* promises that are being rejected, and we return only `result` promise, letting the promise created by finally to dangle.

Comment: So when handling error with catch after the `test` function call, the promise that finally has created is not being handled, hence creating unhandled promise rejection. To handle this we can attach finally handler in test function, to actual promise we are creating or assign promise returned by finally to `result` variable, thus creating a promise chain, which is not created in first case

Comment: @h4ckthepl4net I've added a "how to prevent uncaught rejections" section to the answer. You seem to reached an understanding of what went on in the question, hopefully this will help clarify it further.